# compare part of inserted value and retrieve the values from the particular column in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

- columnx
- 1425795755580/0
- 1425785965412/3

> i have inserted milliseconds/noofdays in db in columnx.Now i want to
>   retrieve that using the currenttime is equal to that milliseconds so
>   for that i have written a query as follows.

`SELECT substr(reminder,0,14) from tablename where substr(reminder,0,14)='1425795755580'`

> ..but i'm unable to get the value can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the below query i solved the issue.

```
SELECT reminderfrom tablename where substr(reminder,0,14)='1425695400443'
```

Thanks Droids.

Answer (score 0):

Your request must be :

```
SELECT tablename.columnx from tablename where tablename.columnx ='1425795755580'
```

What is the string returned by `substr(reminder,0,14)` ?

Comment: dude write earlier what you have written that is working fine.. then i'll accept .